# Two dataset, same color of categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have two datasets with a categorical variable. I want to have the colors in the plot the same when I use this variable.

How can I do this?

This is the code:

```
percmarkt <- ggplot(tabelmarktaandeel, aes(x=Jaar, y=Percentage, fill=Verzekeraar)) + geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y="sum") + scale_fill_manual(values=corp_palette)

percmarkthist <- ggplot(tabelmarktaandeelhist, aes(x=Jaar, y=Percentage, fill=Verzekeraar_Historie)) + geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y="sum") + scale_fill_manual(values=corp_palette)
```

I want the colors for the fill Verzekeraar and Verzekeraar_Historie to be the same, when the name of the categorie is the same.

Comment: Hi, I think there are some good answers in that linked duplicate that should answer your question!

Comment: Yes thank you. It works.